# The new submit question style is stuck and won't let me do anything

Tags: support, status-norepro, asking-questions

I've written a question on stack exchange with the new ui and it's straight up stuck.

It shows do a final review:
[image: Banner: "Please do a final review of your question and then post."]

But then doesn't let me progress, at all!
[image: submit button disabled]

How do I get out of this? what is wrong? why won't it let me post???

There is not even a hint on what should be done next, or why it is stuck in such state

*Update:*

I've tried to ask another question and (thankfully) my question was saved, this time it did pop out a **Review questions** dialog box at the bottom.

Maybe this was just a short internet outage.

Looking into the browser console, in the original tab, it shows  "Uncaught TypeError: can't access dead object":
[image: several of the same error]

Comment: Do any of the other inputs have a red border?

Comment: Is there another box where you have to confirm that non of the existing questions on SO solves your problem?

Comment: @KevinB no red borders or confirmations, there's just few red squiggles in the editor on words like "ffmpeg" and "dshow" but I don't think that's it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this sometimes occurs when SE replies with a payload containing an error of some sort, but the payload doesn't make its way to the UI due to a bug. Try opening your browser console (control-shift-I in some environments), go to the Network tab, and then try again. If it doesn't let you submit, but no error is shown on the UI, look at recent XHR requests and see if any of them contain an error message. That's where I'd start, at least.

Comment: Those "red squiggles", @LemonJumps , are your spell checker telling you "This word does not appear in my dictionary."

Comment: It looks like the errors you're getting may relate to an adblocker you're using - could you try submitting while the blocker is disabled?

Comment: I'm marking this no-repro for the time being. If others are having a similar issue and can give me some repro steps without blockers or userscripts running, that'd be super helpful. :)

Comment: @Catija I can't reproduce it with or without any firefox extensions enabled, seems like it was a very unlucky, one time thing. also sorry for late response, I've been very busy lately. :D